# how to install Resolume 7.1.2 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: wine, video, lutris

I tried installing it with Wine and Lutris, Resolume is not a game but a really fun and useful gpu based real time video mixer program. I have failed and I'm new to linux.

i downloaded form the official website.
https://resolume.com/download/files?file=Resolume_Arena_7_1_2_rev_69101_No_Footage_Installer.exe

can anyone help me run it?

Comment: If that may help a couple of years ago someone reported at https://resolume.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3737&sid=5ab3199d88125f565f644b57543eee87&start=10 that "Resolume Avenue 3 is fully working (Audio and Visual + FX) in Wine 1.2 (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS)". Hopefully there may be ways to run newer versions too.

Comment: From this other report Resolume 7.3 rev 72441 is reported to work too https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=39557